# Kafka streams using context forward from processor called in dsl api

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a processor and would like to call context.forward() in it.  However I feel like I need to set a sink topic for it to actually get forwarded. If I was using the Toplogy I would just .addSource(), .addProcessor(), .addSink().  However with the DSL I have a StreamsBuilder/KStream.  Is there anyway to use context.forward() when calling a processor from the dsl?

NOTE:  I need to use a processor instead of a transform as I have custom logic on when to forward records down stream.

```
stream.process(() -> new WindowAggregatorProcessor(storeName), storeName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stream.process()` is a terminal operation in the DSL. You can use `stream.transform()` instead to get an output stream. A `Transformer` is basically the same as a `Processor`.

Comment: With a transformer dont you need to return the value you want to go down stream.  In my case I have a context.schedule() that may or may not want to forward content.  For your suggestion to work I would need to always have transform() return null and the have context.forward() pass the value to the next operation.  Which I dont think will work?

Comment: What you say will work. Btw: we are currently adding a "FlatTransformer" to allow you to emit more than one value via return. `context.forward` will still be available (it's disadvantage is, that's not type safe; but it works).